# The New Render Window in 2.8

Tags: rendering

So, I've noticed when you render something in version 2.8, it automatically opens a new window, and renders it on that.  What I want to know is this:  Is there anything special about this window, and is there a way to set it so that it renders it in the original window, like it did in version 2.79?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the *Display Mode* for the actual rendering in the *User Prefrences > Interface Editors > Temporary Windows*. If you'd like to get the old behavior back, set 'Render in' to '**Image Editor**' or 'Keep User Interface' and [save a new start-up file](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/defaults.html#saving-defaults).

[image]

Comment: Thx, @brockmann.  So, is the reason it renders in a new window simply for convenience?

Comment: The reason is that the artists at the blender institute got 2 screens to work with :) Not pretty sure... I think it's a general thing that as of 2.8x the guys flatten out that old *ui paradigm* working in one window and this is just one part of it. @RBlong2us

Comment: Well, at least they still give you the option of working with one window.  Thanks for the info.  If any one thinks that there is another reason for there being a second window, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I don't think that's worth it, however you can always search for the actual commit at https://developer.blender.org/ to get more information @RBlong2us

Comment: ah, I was just curious.

Comment: display mode isn't there in 2.91 can someone update?