# Render result in current ui

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm currently using 2.8.2 but this also happens with 2.8.1 when I hit F12 for render it opens a new window, can't seem to find any options to have it display the render result in the current ui layout instead I get a full 1:1 pop up of my render taking over my screen I rather have the render inside of one my window panels. Has this been changed or just removed?

EDIT: apparently it's still there in 2.8.1 but not 2.8.2
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The New Render Window in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147969/the-new-render-window-in-2-8)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it's still there in 2.8.1 but gone  in 2.8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current development version of Blender 2.82 the option can be found in the preferences. The *Interface* tab contains the *Editor* panel, which contains the *Temporary Windows* sub-panel, where the *Render In* option is located.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, this is close but in older versions of Blender the render would just overtake whatever panel was largest in the ui with the image editor window and then you can hit Esc to go back to the previous window. Setting it to "Image Editor" seems to be what I actually wanted.

Comment: Also there in Blender 3.0.1!

Answer (score 0):

In the **Render** menu under the **Display mode** sub-menu you can select various options.

Display Mode

**Full Screen**
- Images are rendered in a maximized Image editor.

**Image Editor**
- Images are rendered in an Image editor.

**New Window**
Images are rendered in a new window.

**Keep User Interface**
- Images are rendered without changing the user interface.

For more information see [top bar documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/interface/window_system/topbar.html)

Comment: "*In the Render menu under the Display mode sub-menu*" ?? What does that mean? The link doesn't show anything related to rendering destination.

Comment: @mins this answer is quite old.  The documentation link is to the current version ... which at the time of posting was correct.  The 2.82 version documentation is now linked and the display mode is shown.  I tested in Blender 2.80.75 today as I still had it installed but the app has been through many changes, so please check the documentation for the version you are interested in.

Comment: Unfortunately it has disappeared since 2.80. In current version (3.1) there is [no display mode sub-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kJ1u.png).

Comment: Think it disappeared in 2.82, but the documentation maybe wasn't up to date.  Regardless, the question from the OP is about 2.82 and so my advice remains the same.  If you cannot find what you need in the current documentation, I would suggest asking in the chat or posting a new question.

Comment: "*I would suggest asking in the chat or posting a new question*": @Robert Gützkow 's answer is valid for current version.

Comment: @mins Good to know, I assume that IS in the current documentation.